# Why won't my UIScrollView Scroll when I use a window based template instead of a view based template?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll

So I have 2 projects, I created one using a the window based application template and one using the view based application template. I created a UIScrollView in both. The view based one works and the window based one doesn't. Does anyone know why? Please help.

Here is my relevant initialization code:

```
@interface Scroller : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[(UIScrollView*)self.view setScrollEnabled:YES];
[(UIScrollView*)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];

}
```

In interface builder I set scroller's view to the UIScrollview, and the UIscrollView's delegate to Scroller. I also set the size of UIScrollView to (320, 800).

Here is where I create the view controller.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

Scroller *scroller = [[Scroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"Scroller" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[window addSubview:scroller.view]; 
[scroller release]; 

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

Is there something I am missing. Please help.

Thx,

Comment: "The view based one works and the window based one doesn't. Does anyone know why?" Could you specify 'works?"

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you, the view based one scrolls and the window based starts at the top, but does not scroll down.